# Getting weird error logs while installing babel cli for node v12

Tags: macos, meteor, babeljs, angular-meteor, fsevents

I have been getting some weird error logs while installing babel cli on my mac machine which has node v12. It seems the error is related to fsevents module which is a dependency for mac. I was trying with the command `yarn global add babel-cli`

I was facing the same issue when trying to update meteor version for a different project.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu1H8.png)

The logs are a lot lengthier than the one attached.

[Full Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cfqxw5Lw4JHiZnpSO2vGcVmJYIBE2rhu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide the full logs, we can't tell what the issue is from the snippet

Comment: @FredStark I have uploaded full logs to my drive. Here's the link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cfqxw5Lw4JHiZnpSO2vGcVmJYIBE2rhu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your full log is missing the lines from the screenshot. Can you post what appears in your terminal?

Comment: Looking at the logs, it looks like it's failing when trying to install `fsevents@1.0.14`, according to the engine compatibility section of the Readme, you need version 2+ to support node 12.
Can you run `npm list --tree` and see which direct dependency is pulling fsevents@1.0.14 in?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This problem can be quite annoying to resolve, and I have been battling with it recently.

It's more of a node 12 problem than a Meteor problem. It looks like a problem with `nan`, but in fact it's likely to be some other library.

I finally solved it by making sure that I had the latest `bcrypt@4.0.1` and `utf-8-validate@5.0.2`. The latter is an indirect dependency, which seemed to make a difference.

Comment: I tried the above options. Didn't work for me. Looks like it is some dependency of angular-meteor-auth package which is causing this issue. I have added full logs in the question.